# Spring Security Struts2 integration libraries

Tags: struts2, spring-security

I'm trying to integrate Spring Security into a Struts2 project. This project doesn't use a dependency resolving tool like Maven, so 
I don't know if I have to add all the Spring Security libraries and their dependencies to make the project work or I can leave those dependencies for later.

Comment: You don't need all of them just pick up what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need `Struts2` jars. I hope you know `struts2` jars.

Second,

> 1.struts2-spring-plugin-2.x.x.jar

Which depends on `Spring Framework`

> 1.spring-expression-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar
>   2.spring-beans-x.x.x.jar
>   3.spring-core-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar
>   4.spring-context-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar
>   5.spring-web-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar
>   6.spring-test-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar
>   7.commons-lang3-3.1.jar
>   8.commons-jci-fam-1.0.jar
>   9.easymock.jar

Additional Support Jars if needed

> 10.spring-aop-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar
>   11.spring-aspects-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar
>   12.spring-context-support-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
>   13.spring-test-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar

You need `Spring Security` Jars

> 1.spring-security-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
>   2.spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
>   3.spring-security-acl-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
>   4.spring-security-aspects-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
>   5.spring-security-config-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
>   6.spring-security-taglibs-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar

Spring Security jars depends on `SPRING Framework` and

> 1.ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar
>   2.spring-tx-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar
>   3.cglib-2.2.jar
>   4.spring-webmvc-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar

And `slf4j` Jars for **logging**

> 1.jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar
>   2.slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
>   3.slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar
>   4.slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
>   5.log4j-1.2.16.jar